# Birthday problem with known number of collisions

Tags: probability, birthday

I find out that the problem I'm trying to solve is related to Birthday problem, specifically to [collision counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Collision_counting):

$$c = n - d + d(\frac{d-1}{d})^n$$

In my case, I know the desired number of collisions `c` and the number of selections `n`.

My goal is to figure out the formula for `d` using `c` and `n`, so I can express that in my program.

Please guide me how to solve this kind of equations, a link to similar examples would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \gt 4$ you will not find a general analytic solution, so you are looking at numerical techniques.  There are many one dimensional rootfinders out there.  Simple [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) is easy to program and as your function is easy to evaluate will probably be fast enough.  Write your function as $f(d)=-c + n - d (1-(\frac{d-1}{d})^n)$ and you are trying to find the $d$ where $f(d)=0$  You know that $f(0) \gt 0$ and should be able to check that $f(n) \lt 0$.  Then split the interval in half and evaluate $f(\frac n2)$.  Replace whichever endpoint has the same sign and continue until the endpoints differ by less than $1$, round to the nearest whole number, and declare victory.